# как натянуть слайдер bootstrap на opencart

Tags: php, opencart, twig

Первый раз натягиваю верстку магазина, на opencart. Подскажите как натянуть свой слайдер, что бы можно было менять и добавлять картинки с админки, т.е в вкладке "баннеры". В carousel.twig, поставить свой код?

Comment: Заранее благодарю

Comment: еще на слайдере, поверх есть текст

Comment: Или подскажите, какой нибудь пошаговый курс, а то в гугле вообще информацию не нашел